# Taylor series for $\frac{1}{(1+x)^t}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm having some trouble finding the Taylor series for the following function at zero (Maclaurin series).
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(1+x)^t}
\end{equation}
Where $t$ is a constant that is greater than zero.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach is to obtain successive derivatives of $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^t}$ with respect to $x$ and then plug it in the Taylor series expansion near $0$. You easily find by induction that
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n\frac{t(t+1) \cdots (t+n-1)}{(1+x)^{t+n}}, \quad n=1,2,\ldots,
$$
leading to

> $$
> \frac{1}{(1+x)^t}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{t(t+1) \cdots (t+n-1)}{n!}x^n
> $$

for $x$ near $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, could you maybe also clarify for me what it means if I am told to write, for example, the third degree Taylor polynomial of the function.

Comment: You are welcome! You may write, for the third degree Taylor polynomial : $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^t}=1-t x+\frac{1}{2} t(t+1) x^2-\frac{1}{6} t(t+1)(t+2) x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^4) $$

Comment: I'm having some trouble figuring out how you calculate those terms.

Comment: Please, if you mean those in my preceding comment, you just have to put $n=1,\,2,\,3$ in the formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$ given in my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get the first term ($-tx$) because I do not get that when I plug in the value for $n$.

Comment: @friedmanfanboy You have that, as $n=1$, $\displaystyle (-1)^n\frac{t(t+1) \cdots (t+n-1)}{n!}x^n $ becomes $\displaystyle (-1)^1\frac{t}{1!}x^1=-tx $.

Comment: I must not be getting what the numerator term means. What exactly happens to the $t(t+1)$ term cause it seems like you're only using the $(t+n-1)$ term.

Comment: When I write $t(t+1) \cdots (t+n-1)$ this is just a generic term, in case $n=1$ the last factor $t+n-1$ is **already** the first one $t$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you very much for your help.