How to find a series representation for $\frac{1}{(1-cx)^n}$?
I am doing some exercises regarding linear recursion.
Some Context: (if needed)
While doing those exercises, I stumbled upon the following:
For a linear recursion $a_n$, one defines $a(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$. Then one multiplies the recursive equation with $x^n$ and then sums up the LHS and the RHS of the equation up to $\infty$. By doing some calculations and a partial fraction decomposition one arives at a step where $a(x)$ is represented by a sum of fraction. One example would be
$a(x)=\frac{-2}{1-x}+\frac{9}{1-3x}$, from an exercise I recently did. Then one can use the formula for the geometric series, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^n=\frac{1}{1-q}$ to get a representation of the fractions as a series. In the stated example this would be $a(x)=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n+9 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(3x)^n$.
Then one can compare the coefficients on the LHS and RHS to get a explicit formula for the recursion.
Question:
The thing is I stumbled upon exercises, where I have powers in the denominator, i.e. something like $a(x)=...+\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}+...$. And I do not know how to get a series representation for those fractions.
One way would be to calculate the taylor series, but this method can get tedious very fast. Are there more elegant (and faster) ways to get a series representation for those kind of fractions.

Hint: You know the series for $\frac{1}{1-cx}$, so maybe an operation can get you a representation of what you're looking for.

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313204/42969, or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1164803/42969

$$\frac1{(1-z)^n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}z^k.$$ Let $z=cx.$

To expand on Thomas's answer one can even replace $n$ with any complex number $\alpha$ and generalize with the Beta function:
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\alpha+k}\frac{1}{\mathrm B(\alpha,k+1)}~z^\alpha$$
For $|z|<1$.

Hint: With the geometric series and the Cauchy product of two infinite series in the toolbox we can start with
$n=2$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-cx)^2}}&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c^kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}c^lx^l\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m}c^kc^{m-k}\right)x^m\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^m1\right)c^mx^m\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(m+1)c^mx^m}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We observe in (1) the coefficient $(m+1)c^m$. We go one step further and check whether we can derive a pattern for the coefficients of $\frac{1}{(1-cx)^n}$. We calculate $\frac{1}{(1-cx)^3}=\frac{1}{(1-cx)^2}\frac{1}{1-cx}$ and obtain
$n=3$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-cx)^3}}&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)c^kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}c^lx^l\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m}(k+1)c^kc^{m-k}\right)x^m\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{k+1}{1}\right)c^mx^m\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+2}{2}c^mx^m}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
In (2) we write $k+1=\binom{k+1}{1}$ and recall the Hockey-stick identity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{k+r}{r}=\binom{m+r+1}{r+1}
\end{align*}

We can generalise (1) and (3) by claiming
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-cx)^n}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+m-1}{m}c^mx^m}
\end{align*}
which can be shown by induction on $n$.

Note: A short way is to use the binomial series expansion and the binomial identity $\binom{-n}{m}=\binom{n+m-1}{m}(-1)^m$.

you always find a different way to explain basics, and reading them make me happy $+1$

@NotaSalmonFish: Many thanks for your nice comment and the upvote. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)
